# linux socket :no route to host on planetLab machine

Tags: linux, sockets

i run my code between two windows machine and it works.However,i move server side on PlanetLab machine . Client run error no route to host.It seems a firewall problem,but i don't have root and sudo privileges.Can I have another way to try? Thank you.

```
traceroute to 140.114.89.45 (140.114.89.45), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  140.118.125.254 (140.118.125.254)  2.077 ms  2.294 ms  2.569 ms
2  140.118.250.105 (140.118.250.105)  0.269 ms  0.337 ms  0.378 ms
3  * 140.111.230.25 (140.111.230.25)  1.377 ms  1.633 ms
4  * * 140.111.230.42 (140.111.230.42)  1.408 ms
5  * bb-MOE-N.TANet.edu.tw (203.72.43.6)  1.747 ms *
6  * * bb-NTHU-TWAREN.TANet.edu.tw (192.83.196.114)  4.136 ms
7  * * *
8  * c7609-2-c7609C.nthu.edu.tw (140.114.1.190)  4.429 ms  4.370 ms
9  140.114.2.141 (140.114.2.141)  4.377 ms  4.399 ms *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * cs744.cs.nthu.edu.tw (140.114.89.45)  4.134 ms !X
```

Comment: It maybe allows ssh way such safe way .

Answer (score 1):

"No route to host" is generally a *routing* problem, not a firewall blocking the connection. Try the following measures:

- Resolve the IP address of the destination (e.g. using `nslookup` or `ping`)
- Run `traceroute` to the destination machine and see where the packets start dropping. That way you will know *where* your routing is messed up.
- Check if the destination is a multi-home host, resolving to multiple IPs. It could be that you have to use a different IP to reach it.

Based on your `traceroute` output, it looks like the administrator of `cs744.cs.nthu.edu.tw` prohibits traffic. It is impossible to tell whether it is for your subnet or in general. You should contact the sysadmin of that host/net to figure out.

Comment: i can resolve ip address and hostname ,and i run trace route 13 "  * * cs744.cs.nthu.edu.tw (140.114.89.45)" 4.134 ms !X ,it is my client connect's distination

Comment: It might be useful if you add full (or at least relevant pieces of) `traceroute` output in your question text.